# Code hinting in eclipse PDT only after saving

Tags: ide, eclipse-pdt

This is kind of irritating, but I am using Eclipse PDT and code hinting only works on already saved portions of data. That is, assume I write code:

```
$o = new SomeObject();
$o->
```

(assuming SomeObject has public properties) Now when I hit Ctrl+space I get "No matches found". If I save and then hit Ctrl+space, suddenly PDT *knows* properties of SomeObject. Now let's assume I have this code saved:

```
$o = new SomeObject();
$o->destroyTheUniverse();
```

When I place caret right after **->** and hit Ctrl+space hinting works. But if I add another line of code

```
$o->
```

It won't give me any hints about the newly written code. That makes coding rather irritating.
I tried to look through the preferences but failed to find the solution (the same for Googling) so I am asking here - how to make PDT smarter with code hinting?